# PythonAnywhere Django 404 Page Not Found for Homepage

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, pythonanywhere

I know there is a similar post like this one. I've reviewed it and it is quite different from what I'm experiencing at the moment on [Pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com)

I'm trying to deploy my rango tutorial project that I completed through tangowithdjango.com onto Pythonanywhere.com. When I try to open the site (url is ragzputin.pythonanywhere.com), I get this page:

[image]

Here's my urls.py file for my project:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns(
    'django.views.static',
    (r'media/(?P<path>.*)',
    'serve',
     {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

If you guys need some extra information, here's my app urls.py (app name is rango):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name="about"),
    url(r'^add_category/$', views.add_category, name="add_category"),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/add_page/$', views.add_page,   name="add_page"),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/$', views.category, name="category"),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name="register"),
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name="login"),
    url(r'^restricted/$', views.restricted, name="restricted"),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name="logout"),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name="profile"),
    url(r'^goto/$', views.track_url, name="track_url"),
    url(r'^like_category/$', views.like_category, name="like_category"),
    url(r'^suggest_category/$', views.suggest_category, name="suggest_category"),
    url(r'^auto_add_page/$', views.auto_add_page, name="auto_add_page"),
)
```

As you can see from the 404 page above, the server is not able to get to the main page which starts with '^rango/'. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add url for home page into the project's urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'rango.views.index', name="index"),
    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And don't forget to remove the same (first) url from `rango/urls.py`.

The other option is to add redirect from `/` to `/rango/`. If you choose this option then project's urls.py should be:

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/rango/')),
    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Of course in this case `rango/urls.py` should be untouched.